# integrate stripe js in react withnode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I want to set up a stripe checkout using react and node.js. Compiles in  node terminal but when I inspect the localhost:3000 page, this error message is returned

Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Cart`.

1. in tr (at cart/index.jsx:66)
2. in Cart (at src/index.jsx:8)

```
  <tbody>{
                  items.map(item => (
                   <tr>
                   <td>{item.name}</td>
                   <td>
                    <img
                      src={`/images/${item.apiId}.jpg`}
                      alt={item.name}
                      width={180}
                   />
                    </td>
                    <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                    <td>{formatPrice(item.price)}</td>
                </tr>)
                 )}
               <tr>
```

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import Cart from "./components/cart/"


ReactDOM.render(
    <Cart stripeToken = "test-token" />,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you render a list of elements, you need to add a `key` prop to each element so React can keep track of which elements to re-render if the component's state or props ever change. In your case, to fix that warning message you would add the `key` prop with a value that is unique to each table row. For example:

```
        <tbody>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <tr key={item.apiId}> // Makes the warning go away
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>
                <img
                  src={`/images/${item.apiId}.jpg`}
                  alt={item.name}
                  width={180}
                />
              </td>
              <td>{item.quantity}</td>
              <td>{formatPrice(item.price)}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
```

In this case, I'm using the `item.apiId` as the key under the assumption that the `apiId`'s are unique to each element in the items array. It is somewhat common to see the item's index in the array being used as a unique key, but that approach falls apart quickly if the order of the elements ever changes.

You can read more on the key prop and why it's needed here:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
- https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop

Comment: That did the trick and the warning is gone, but now it says : v3:1 Uncaught IntegrationError: Invalid stripe.redirectToCheckout parameter:

Comment: Glad to hear the first issue is fixed! I would recommend opening up a second question for the new error as it doesn't seem related.